# Web Api ignores CreateErrorResponse in Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a base controller:

```
public abstract class EntityController<T> : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateModel]
    public abstract IHttpActionResult Create(T dto);

    [HttpPut]
    [ValidateModel]
    public abstract IHttpActionResult Update(T dto);

    [HttpDelete]
    public abstract IHttpActionResult Delete(int id);
}
```

And a derived controller:

```
public class CustomerTypeController : EntityController<CustomerTypeDTO>
{
    [ApiAuthorize(Right = Rights.CustomerType, Action = Action.Create)]
    public override IHttpActionResult Create(CustomerTypeDTO  customerType)
    {
        return Save(customerType);
    }

    [ApiAuthorize(Right = Rights.CustomerType, Action = Action.Update)]
    public override IHttpActionResult Update(CustomerTypeDTO  customerType)
    {
        return Save(customerType);
    }

    private IHttpActionResult Save(CustomerTypeDTO customerType)
    {
        //service layer save customer type
    }
}
```

The base controller has a [ValidateModel] on the actions, whilst the derived controller sets it's own [ApiAuthorize] attribute. The attributes are fired in the right order (first ApiAuthorize and then ValidateModel). I have not set the order and I don't know if it's possible.

The ApiAuthorize looks like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple=false)]
public class ApiAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);

        //Do some checks...

        if (!authorized)
          actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, new CustomNotAuthorizedException());
    }
 }
```

However the problem is that even although the attribute creates an error response, the action still proceeds further by going into ValidateModel and then into the action itself.

How is it possible to stop the api from processing the request further at the Authorize and ValidateModel levels?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the Authorize attribute code was not setting the response. It has to be like this:

```
if (!authorized)
{
    var response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, new CustomNotAuthorizedException());
    actionContent.Response = response;
}
```